# Uncaught token : when want to get json by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'd like to get information in JSON format of the current year from [http://basicdata.ru/api/json/calend](http://basicdata.ru/api/json/calend?callback=jQuery18302508875399362296_1449495090243&_=1449495090322).

I use:

```
var url = 'http://basicdata.ru/api/json/calend';
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Getting data: " + data);
    }
})
```

I have read many sites and all used this structure, but i have an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

What I have done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data returned from that url isn't formatted as `jsonp`.

Try `dataType: 'json',`, instead.

Comment: if i use "json", i can't get information from site because it's in other domain.

Comment: So, the server should return a jsonp response, then.